# C# main method cannot run program

Tags: sum, numbers

I am doing this C# code for my homework for calculating sum and substract
for the sum it is working fine, but I don't know how to code for two math equation as a code. I am thinking of the way I put the main method and brackets? There's only one error which what I have commented // on it.
Thank you in advance for your time.

```
using System;

namespace pg392mod
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            int firstNumber = 10;
            int secondNumber = 2;
            int result;

            //2 call the method calculatesum and pass the 2 parameters to it
            result = CalculateSum(firstNumber, secondNumber);

            //3 write to console the result of the sum of the 2 numbers
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of {0} and {1} is = {2}.", firstNumber, secondNumber, result);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static int CalculateSum(int n1, int n2)
        {
            int sum;
            sum = n1 + n2;
            return sum;

        }

       //this is the error private static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            int firstNumber = 10;
            int secondNumber = 2;
            int result;

            //2 call the method calculatesum and pass the 2 parameters to it
            result = CalculateSum(firstNumber, secondNumber);

            //3 write to console the result of the sum of the 2 numbers
            Console.WriteLine("Substraction of {0} and {1} is = {2}.", firstNumber, secondNumber, result);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static int CalculateSubstract(int n1,int n2)
        {
            int sub;
            sub = n1 - n2;
            return sub;           


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown as you duplicated `main` definition. Items declared `static` must be unique as there is only one instance of them within the scope that they are declared.

Commenting out the line leaves you with a block of code, encompassed by `{` and `}` that is left floating and not within a defined scope.

The following would be better:

```
using System;

namespace pg392mod
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int firstNumber = 10;
            int secondNumber = 2;
            int result;

            //2 call the method calculatesum and pass the 2 parameters to it
            result = CalculateSum(firstNumber, secondNumber);

            //3 write to console the result of the sum of the 2 numbers
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of {0} and {1} is = {2}.", firstNumber, secondNumber, result);

            Console.ReadLine();

            //2 call the method calculatesubtract and pass the 2 parameters to it
            result = CalculateSubtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);

            //3 write to console the result of the sum of the 2 numbers
            Console.WriteLine("Substraction of {0} and {1} is = {2}.", firstNumber, secondNumber, result);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static int CalculateSubtract(int n1,int n2)
        {
            int sub;
            sub = n1 - n2;
            return sub;           
        }
        public static int CalculateSum(int n1, int n2)
        {
            int sum;
            sum = n1 + n2;
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! For a second I thought it worked but now both of them added up. I need one sum and one subtraction thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Ah yes - that's why I replaced the second call to `CalculateSum` with `CalculateSubtract` - sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Oh and I corrected the spelling mistake for the function `CalculateSubstract` to `CalculateSubtract`

Comment: Thank you so much I am still new here and figuring it out but I really appreciate your time and help!